# Conductive "App Brick" without human contact

Tags: software, electronics

This may not be entirely LEGO-related, but more related to touch screen technology.

I'd like the LEGO app brick (http://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6103777) to register a touch on a touch screen even if I'm not touching the brick. I'd like to put a LEGO construction with such bricks at the bottom on the screen, and register a touch event.

Is that at all possible?

Comment: My initial feelings are "no" because it requires the capacitance of the human body to make these go. But such hypotheses should be tested.

Comment: Saw something similar to this on facebook: https://www.facebook.com/groups/legomindstorms/permalink/614663002015263/

Comment: Are you trying to set up a model where you can push a Lego brick and it pushes something that touches a button on a screen?

Comment: I want to do this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CgvnIYSiTE) with minifigures

Answer (score 2):

If you are planing on physically touching the brick that will then touch the screen then you could use a trick similar to that used by [capacitive gloves](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0069IUZPM)

There just needs to be a conductive medium between your finger and the screen so you could add a thin strip of copper tape or anything metallic to bridge the gap between your finger and the touch screen that is created by the insulation of the plastic brick.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm having a little bit of a hard time understanding what you mean, but then again it is a harder problem, so bear with me here.

What I'm getting here, and tell me in the comments if I'm wrong, is that you want your phone to "hear" that you touched the brick, without having actually interacting with the brick at all.

Rather, you want to modify the program so that you can touch a GUI button and the program will "hear" the touch event as broadcast by your phone, rather than by the brick.

This will be entirely program-based, and will not require any "hacking" of your brick. But it does mean that you will be required to make a new version of the program to include this function, the false touch, and that really depends on how good you are at programming ios, or whatever language your touchscreen device is based on.

I know this isn't completely as helpful as you might desire, but this might not be the best place to ask about programming, and programming is what it will come down to. We do have an SE site for that!